# Currency XE Calculations

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I've got a simple single page web app. It fetches currency data (in USD) from two different APIs, upon successfully retrieval, the `promise` is resolved, and some calculations work out the **GBP/Bitcoin** exchange rate.

I'm trying to find a clean way to then flip to the exchange rate ie.

**Default:** Show GBP/Bitcoin
**Toggle button:** Show Bitcoin/GBP

Any help from you would be much appreciated.

*The app is build with React, but that should make a difference.*

**App.js**

```
axios.all([this.getGBP(), this.getBitcoin()])
  .then(axios.spread( (gbpVal, bitcoinVal) => { 
    const gbp  = xVal.data.rates.GBP;
    const bitcoin  = yVal.data.bpi.USD.rate_float;
    const xOfy = this.xOfy(gbp, bitcoin);
    const yOfX = this.yOfX(bitcoin, gbp);
  }));


getGBP() {
    // returns gbp from api
}

getBitcoin() {
    // returns bitcoin from api
}

xOfy(unit, value) {
    return 1 / (unit * value);
}

yOfX(unit, value) {
  return unit * value;
}
```

**Request #1 - gives USD/Bitcoin**

```
{  
   "bpi":{  
      "USD":{  
         "code":"USD",
         "symbol":"&#36;",
         "rate":"4,346.6913",
         "description":"United States Dollar",
         "rate_float":4346.6913
      }
   }
}
```

**Request #2 - gives GBP/USD**

```
{
  "base": "USD",
  "rates": {
    "GBP": 0.762441,
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are working along the write type of lines. If you focus on making your functions a little more pure, they will work for you. Also that api can return both those values against GBP, instead of USD, if that makes it easier?

Comment: Yeah that's the approach I took in the end (using less specific function). I am not able to get the GBP values unfortunately due to the API setup.

Comment: Oh yeah - sorry I've just seen that it requires a pay subscription get the /GBP values. Glad you got it working.